# Are simple triggers attached to sheets or spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Because I've seen the terms used a little interchangeably in other questions, my question is using the term Spreadsheet to refer to a specific Google Sheets document, and the term Sheet to refer to the individual sheets within that document available as tabs at the bottom of the window.

I have an event management project where events are represented by individual sheets. I have a template sheet which will be duplicated programmatically as users create new events.

On my template sheet, I have an onEdit trigger set up which works well — when the user edits a particular cell, it programmatically affects other cells.

However, when I duplicate my template, the new sheet does not seem to be working. Interestingly, when I edit the cell, the Executions screen shows new entries for onEdit, but the associated function is not being run (I have Logger statements at the top level of the function, but the Executions screen states "No logs are available for this execution."

**Is my trigger only attached to the original sheet?** If so, why is the Executions screen reporting triggers being run? And if they are attached to sheets (instead of the spreadsheet), is there a way to duplicate the triggers when I duplicate the sheet?

I'm an experienced JavaScript developer but a novice with Apps Script. If this all seems like it ought to work then I'll assume I have some other error I need to track down. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your onEdit function is asking for the Active Spreadsheet and that spreadsheet gives you the sheet.

e.g.

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Template");
```

Comment: Thank you! I am checking for the active spreadsheet like you suggest, but in double-checking for that I think I've stumbled on the answer... the error was in my code and had nothing to do with the trigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an error in my code that was unrelated to the trigger ownership issue... it looks like triggers are attached to the spreadsheet (not the sheet) and they work as I expected (when I don't have some other code error mucking things up).